# How Can I make docker-compose settings that allow private IP access from remote machine on same network inside docker container mac

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, ip, docker-for-mac

I've set up a server on a remote Linux machine on the same network. I can access this server from my mac computer with private IP `http://172.30.1.50/`.

However, when I try to access this address within my docker container with the following settings it did not work. I found that `network_mode: host` could help this problem but it does not work in docker for mac.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  external_admin:
    image: external_admin
    build:
      context: ./external_admin/
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./external_admin:/usr/src/app
    command: python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000
    env_file:
      - ./env_files/external_admin.dev.env
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
```

Is there any way to enable private networking within this docker-compose file?

Comment: Do you have a proxy?

Comment: No, I didn't configure the proxy server right now.